# ADAL .Net Core MVC redirect to Angular app

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core

I'm puzzled about how I can achieve the following:

I'm implementing the On-behalf-of flow with Azure AD. I have a .Net Core MVC app where I first log in. After that I have a simple redirect to Angular application where I am passing an access token in the url and I want to authenticate with that token. Here is where my problem comes up - how can I pass this token using the adal-angular4 library to ultimately get a new token for my app and log in as the user as in the MVC app?

My code for redirecting to the Angular app:

```
public IActionResult RedirectToSecondApp()
    {
        string userObjectID = User.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;
        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(AzureAdOptions.Settings.Authority,
                                                    new NaiveSessionCache(userObjectID, HttpContext.Session));
        var accessToken = authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().First().AccessToken;
        return Redirect($"https://localhost:44377?token={accessToken}");
    }
```

Code for the Angular component using AdalService:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { AdalService } from "adal-angular4";
import { CookieService } from "ngx-cookie-service";

@Component({
  selector: "app-toolbar",
  templateUrl: "./toolbar.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./toolbar.component.css"]
})
export class ToolbarComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private adalService: AdalService,
    private cookieService: CookieService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.adalService.handleWindowCallback();
  }

  login() {
    this.adalService.login();
  }

  logout() {
    this.adalService.logOut();
  }

  get authenticated(): boolean {
    return this.adalService.userInfo.authenticated;
  }
}
```

Comment: Access token is used to access resources which protected by Azure AD . Your scenario is not suitable with [On-Behalf-Of flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow) , the access token is pass to second app as query string . You'd better implement authentication in your angular app and acquire access token for that protected api .

Comment: Ok maybe I have wrote something wrong. Question is pretty easy: How to pass already aquired token from ASP.NET MVC app to Angular App?

Comment: You can pass with query string or http header .

Comment: Yes that is totally known...But what can we do with it? How to "init" ADAL with this token? Or how to get new token for this new site?

Comment: You can't use access token in your angular application for sign-in . Your angular app still need to authenticate  with AAD .

Comment: Isn't that what SSO is all about? We just want to log in in one place (ASP.NET MVC) and use this on all other sites (for example Angular Apps)
Login in inside APP1, use it in APP2,APP3,APP4,....,APPn

Comment: If you have same browser session cookie you can achieve SSO among applications with same identity provider . That is not related to access token . You misunderstand the scenario .

Comment: That is obvious that all apps are using same identity provider... but how to avoid asking about credentials/identity once we already have it confirmed in one of those apps?